# CSS Marker effect combined with gradient text

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to achieve a result in CSS where a title is displayed with a marker-like effect and a gradient text color.
This is the code I made up for the two effects:

```
/* GRADIENT TEXT */
h1 {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#229, #aaf);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

/* MARKER EFFECT */
em {
background: gray;
}
```

If I try to combine the two, the marker effect just overcomes the gradient text.
This is probably caused by the fact that both define a background, but I don't know how to solve it.
Thanks

Comment: show your html pls

Comment: Those are just the css for the individual elements.
Anyway, Andy Hoffman solved the problem.

Comment: Sometimes, the problem may lie in the html structure, and this applies not only to your question. Please take a note to show all sides of your project in the future (html, css, js etc.) for the convenience of the person who will give you the answer to your question.

Comment: Yes, evidently nested <em> works.
Anyway in this case there was basically no structure, so I didn't put it in the post.
Thanks for the advice, I'll think about it in future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is create a child element inside of `em` and apply the gradient there.

```html
<h1>
  <em>
    <span>Testing</span>
  </em>
</h1>
```

```css
h1 span {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#229, #aaf);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

/* MARKER EFFECT */
em {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <em>
    <span>Testing</span>
  </em>
</h1>
```

Comment: That's literally perfect. I tried making it in this way before, but evidently I had made some error.
Thank you so much